# IEnumerable to List, not returning data

Tags: c#, linq, generics

```
 Public class Class1
    {
       Public int Id {get; set;}
       Public int code {get; set;}
       Public int item1 {get; set;}
       Public int item2 {get; set;}
       Public string data {get; set;}
    }  

    //List filled here
    List<Class1> MyList = GetData();

    int[] codes = {1, 2, 3};       

    IEnumerable<Class1> groupItems = new List<Class1>();

    //Grouping and ordering logic here
    foreach(int code in codes)
    {
        groupItems =   MyList.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                        .Where(w => w.Any(a => a.Code = code)
                        .Select(s => new 
                                    { key = s.Key, 
                                      items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                                               .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
                                     }
                                )
                                .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
                                .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items);
     }

     MyList.Clear();
     MyList.InsertRange(0, groupItems.ToList());
```

From the above code output, MyList is empty in the result. What I am doing wrong here?

On the groupItems it is Ienumerable and while adding to MyList. I am converting to List using ToList().

Comment: From a quick glance, it might be because you use `a.Code = code` as one = instead of `==` (`a.Code == code`)

Comment: @stephen.vakil: Actually, that shouldn't compile at all, for multiple reasons.

Comment: @Slaks:  my code or the code in the question?  I assumed the code in the question compiled because the question was, why is it empty, and not, why doesn't this compile.

Comment: @stephen.vakil: I mean the question.  It's missing a `)`, and it can't convert `int` to `bool`.

Comment: It was an typo, I am using comparison op == there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid the for, It will always return the last result from `groupItems` that can be an empty list. Use Contains in `code` instead.

```
groupItems =   MyList.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                        .Where(w => codes.Contains(w.Code))
                        .Select(s => new 
                                    { key = s.Key, 
                                      items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                                               .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
                                     }
                                )
                                .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
                                .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items);
```

Comment: the where condition is not compiling.

Comment: Which error? I don't have all those classes can't help you this way!

Comment: `w` is `IGrouping<int, Class1>`, thus not having `Code` property. You need to switch `GroupBy` and `Where` (which is better anyway)

Comment: @IvanStoev yeah you are right! Good point! I just focused on the for that doesn't make any sense there!

Comment: I know! But I think OP missed that part and concentrated on the irrelevant one (not that the code he posted is compiling either). We are all shooting in the dark :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Fals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2072198/fals) did a good attempt, but the query just doesn't make sense. The same result could be achieved simply by

```
var items = from e in MyList where codes.Contains(e.Code)
            orderby e.Id, e.Item1, e.Item2 select e;
```

(I usually prefer the lambda syntax, but this is one of the cases when LINQ syntax fits better)

**EDIT:** But let forget about redundancy and inefficiency of the query and get back to the original issue. **Fals** already did that in his answer, but seems you missed that part. What is wrong with your code is that you are defining a variable outside of the loop, then inside the loop you just **assign** a value to the **same variable**, and finally you **use** the variable after exiting the loop. Which doesn't make sense because the variable will contain what you have assigned in the last iteration. In your case, even if `MyList` is not empty, if there are no items with `Code == 3`, you'll get an empty result. It's similar to writing something like this

```
var random = new Random();
int result = 1234;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    result = random.Next(3);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

and asking why it is printing zero sometimes.

Comment: I am grouping and sorting the items on the group.

Comment: Correct, but then "ungroup" them with `SelectMany`. So the result is the same.